# How to insert Empty Text Box value into SQL 2008 database, through stored procedure?

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert empty text box value into  database by stored procedure.But i do
not know how to pass null values through stored procedure please help me.   My Class is

```
public Void empqualadd(string id, string name, string qual1)   
  {
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertQual");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MachID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qualification1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = qual1;
conn.nonquery(cmd);
  }
```

My Button Click is,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
 mas.empqualadd(ddis.SelectedItem.Text,
 txtfname.Text,ddqual.SelectedItem.Text);        
  }
```

I have a connection clas     too,

```
public Connection()
   {
        conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=SIGNET- SOFTWARE\SA;database=manjilas;Integrated security=true");
        cmd = null;
   }
public void nonquery(SqlCommand cmd)//for insert,delete,update
   {
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
   {
conn.Close();
   }
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
   }
```

It  works fine for insert data if text box is not empty.What changes I should made in class to pass null values?
Please Help me.Thanks in advance....

Comment: There a lot of things wrong in your code as far as I see. 1) Would be better if we see definition of `InsertQual` sp. 2) It is `ExecuteNonQuery` not `nonquery`. 3) Your `empqualadd` method doesn't even return any `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MachID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? (object)DbNull.Value : id;
```

Also why are you passing string value when column data type is int?

Comment: Nitin Varpe,Error 13 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'.

Comment: You can accept it as answer if that solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

This also works fine.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qual2)&!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clg2)&!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mark2)&!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year2))                             
          {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qualification2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = qual2.Length > 0 ? qual2 : (object)DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@College2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clg2.Length > 0 ? clg2 : (object)DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mark2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mark2.Length > 0 ? mark2 : (object)DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =year2.Length > 0 ? year2 : (object)DBNull.Value;
            conn.nonquery(cmd);
          }
```